# how can I rename multiple files by inserting a character?

Tags: rename

I have many files of the form

sw001
sw002
sw003
...

I want to insert a period between the sw's and the number values.  How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On Linux:

```
rename 'sw' 'sw.' sw*
```

On Debian, Ubuntu and derivatives, use `rename.ul` instead of `rename` (`rename` is a different file renaming command on those distributions).

Comment: Whups.  Wrong link. :(

Comment: @Daniel: What do you mean "wrong link"?

Comment: I edited my comment - apparently there *is* a second utility by the name `rename` out there.  Which is awesome.  I linked to the wrong manual page, but didn't notice because they are close enough...

Comment: Gotcha. It's interesting that you say the perl rename is usually the default -- I've never run into it before at all. As you say, the rename I'm familiar with should be on most linux boxen, shipping with util-linux.

Comment: I am as surprised as you are, in the opposite direction. :)

Comment: @ryran Debian and derivatives ship a different utility under the name `rename`.

Comment: Ahhh. I use Ubuntu occasionally but I guess I had never noticed. Thanks for the explanation ... and edit .. @Gilles.

Answer (score 8):

If you don't have `rename` and don't feel like downloading it, use this:

```
for file in sw*; do
    mv "$file" "${file/sw/sw.}"
done
```

Comment: Be aware that the pattern substitution `${file/sw/sw.}"` also matches files like `FOOsw001`. Besides - this kind of substitution is not supported by all shells. Removing a prefix pattern should be more appropriate and portable: `"$sw.{file#sw}"`

Comment: @maxschlepzig I suppose it would, but because of the glob all names it encounters necessarily begin with `sw`. Good to point out in general though.

Answer (score 1):

If you can can express the transformation as a Perl regular expression, rename that ships with Perl is a great choice.  It applies a Perl expression to each filename, then changes the name if it is different.  Often, a Perl regular expression substitution is what you want:

```
rename 's/sw/sw./' sw*
```

This is different from the [rename(1)](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rename) that ships with util-linux-ng, but normally the Perl version is the default.  See `man 1 rename` to check which one your system has.

Comment: Can you help me to understand what the / notation means?

Comment: Hopefully that edit is clearer: the man page was for a different utility with the same name, and I didn't notice because it was close enough.  The Perl rename applies a Perl expression; 's///' is a regular expression substitution.

Comment: If this `rename` expression is indeed a regular expression, the `.` character would mean "any one character", so it should be escaped in order to be taken literally.

Comment: @hesse, it would in the match part, not in the replacement part. :)

Comment: The Perl version is the default in Debian and derivatives including Ubuntu. It's not shipped by other distributions.