# how can I rename multiple files by removing a character or string?

Tags: rename

As a follow-up to my [previous question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/33261/how-can-i-rename-multiple-files-by-inserting-a-character), if I have multiple files of the form

```
sw.ras.001
sw.ras.002
sw.ras.003
…
```

What command can I use to remove the `ras.` in the middle of all the files?

Comment: Do you want to remove *only* the `ras`, i.e. end up with `sw..001`, or the `ras.`, leaving `sw.001`?

Comment: i'd probably want to remove the 'ras.'.  would the command be very different?

Comment: No, just whether you include the `\.` in the patterns.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You can do this with a fairly small modification of either answer from the last question:

```
rename s/ras\.// sw.ras.*
```

or

```
for file in sw.ras.*; do
    mv "$file" "${file/ras./}"
done
```

Explanation:

`rename` is a `perl` script that takes a `perl` regular expression and a list of files, applies the regex to each file's name in turn, and renames each file to the result of applying the regex.  In our case, `ras` is matched literally and `\.` matches a literal `.` (as `.` alone indicates any character other than a newline), and it replaces that with nothing.

The `for` loop takes all files that start with `sw.ras.` (standard shell glob) and loops over them. `${var/search/replace}` searches `$var` for `search` and replaces the first occurrence with `replace`, so `${file/ras./}` returns `$file` with the first `ras.` removed. The command thus renames the file to the same name minus `ras.`. Note that with this search and replace, `.` is taken literally, not as a special character.

Comment: Could you explain your answer to others learning from? What "s/ras\.// sw.ras.*" do? I guess I know it but I want to be sure, and other can learn too. Second option same way.

Comment: @H_7 Good idea, I've added an explanation.

Comment: Is `${file/ras./}` used a lot these days? If I have to delete a substring I use `sed` with substitute `s//` which seems more logical or rational.

Comment: Just read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2372739/1705829) and understand that `sed` for filename-change is even more cryptic and should not be used at all.

Answer (score 17):

Another option is to use mmv (Mass MoVe and rename):

```
mmv '*ras.*' '#1#2'
```

Don't forget to use the single quotes around your patterns, otherwise the stars will be expanded at the shell level.

The utility is not always available but if it's not, you can install it with:

```
sudo apt-get install mmv
```

See the man page [here](http://ss64.com/bash/mmv.html).

Comment: That's a great tool!!!

Comment: Not many people are answering this kind of question with a response which allows you to _copy_ the file and rename, thanks!

Answer (score 6):

In any POSIX-compliant shell (`bash`, `dash`, `ksh`, etc):

```
for file in sw.ras.[[:digit:]][[:digit:]][[:digit:]]; do
    mv "${file}" "${file/ras\./}"
done
```

Or with `rename`:

```
rename 's/ras\.//' sw.ras.[[:digit:]][[:digit:]][[:digit:]]
```

Answer (score 3):

I recently had to do a bulk rename of a number of files where I had to replace the last occurrence of a character where the character occurred multiple times in the filenames. In this particular case I had to replace the last dash `-` with an underscore `_`, turning this:

```
some-long-file-name.ext
```

into this:

```
some-long-file_name.ext
```

It took some time but this finally did it:

```
for FILE in *; do mv $FILE ${FILE%-*}_${FILE##*-}; done
```

Here:

- `${i%-*}` matches the begining of the filename up to the last occurrence of the dash `-`
- `${file##*-}` matches the rest of the filename after the last occurrence of the dash `-`

Answer (score 0):

Using find, xargs and sed:

```
find -name 'sw.ras.*' -print0 | sed -ze "p;s/\.ras//" | xargs -0 -n2 mv
```

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4793892/recursively-rename-files-using-find-and-sed#comment60553396_11709995

Answer (score -1):

How do you delete the ads in a filestring?

11/06/2020  06:45 PM        30,534,952 1. Installing Cisco Routers--- [ DevCourseWeb.com ] ---.mp4
11/06/2020  06:45 PM        26,577,869 2. Installing Cisco Switch--- [ DevCourseWeb.com ] ---.mp4
11/06/2020  06:45 PM        24,517,510 3. Installing Cisco ASA--- [ DevCourseWeb.com ] ---.mp4
11/06/2020  06:45 PM        21,726,183 4. Installing Cisco IOS XRv Router--- [ DevCourseWeb.com ] ---.mp4
11/06/2020  06:45 PM        21,918,964 5. Installing Cisco Nexus 7000--- [ DevCourseWeb.com ] ---.mp4
11/06/2020  06:45 PM        31,551,814 6. Installing Cisco Nexus 9000--- [ DevCourseWeb.com ] ---.mp4
11/06/2020  06:45 PM        24,567,825 7. Installing Cisco CSR 1000v Router--- [ DevCourseWeb.com ] ---.mp4
11/06/2020  06:45 PM        78,034,899 8. Installing Cisco ISE--- [ DevCourseWeb.com ] ---.mp4
10/08/2020  10:35 AM               172 Bonus Courses + Project Files.url

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/425919)