# Rename all the files in a folder such that it removes the text between two same characters

Tags: rename

I have huge number of files in folders whose names are as following:

```
abc.test.txt
edf.main.txt
num2.tb.doc
file3.map.csv
file4.test.csv
```

I would like these files to be renamed such a way that the text in between the `.` is removed and above files are renamed as following :

```
abc.txt
edf.txt
num2.doc
file3.csv
file4.csv
```

Is this possible?

I found something similar but doesn't satisfy what I need to.

[how can I rename multiple files by removing a character or string?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/33279/how-can-i-rename-multiple-files-by-removing-a-character-or-string)

Comment: Yes, it is possible. You can do it in a for loop. Have you tried playing with it?

Comment: Are there files named e.g. `ab.cd.ef.gh` (that is, three or more dots) and if so, should those be renamed too and how ?

Answer (score 2):

In zsh, use [`zmv`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/User-Contributions.html#index-zmv). Run `autoload -U zmv` or put that in your ``/.zshrc`, then

```
zmv '(*).*(.*)' '$1$2'
```

or

```
zmv -w '*.*.*' '$1.$3'
```

Alternatively, if you have the `prename` command (Perl script that applies an expression to each file name):

```
prename 's/\..*\././' *.*.*
```

With only tools that are available on every POSIX system, use a shell [loop](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-for), and [parameter expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) to extract the parts of the name.

```
for x in *.*.*; do
  mv -- "$x" "${x%.*.*}.${x##*.}"
done
```

Comment: @aippili Please do not post comments to say “thank you”: [upvote](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-up) answers that you find helpful (one more reputation point and you'll be able to do this). If you think that one answer fully solves your problem, please [mark it as accepted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) (this will give you that missing rep point, by the way). For more information, see [the help center](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 1):

Using the perl rename utility:

```
prename 's/\.[^.]*\././' *
```

`prename` allows you to rename files using perl expressions.

On some systems, the same program is called `rename` rather than (or as well as) `prename`.  There are other programs called `rename` which work very differently - check the `rename` man page on your system to be sure.

e.g. by default, `rename` on Debian systems is a symlink to `prename` (via the `/etc/alternatives` system).  Other distros may differ.

Debian also has a package called `rename` which contains an enhanced version of `prename` called `file-rename`.  It's a newer, updated version of the same script.  It has a higher priority in alternatives, so installing the package will change the `rename` symlink to `file-rename`.

Answer (score -1):

This should take care of it

```
for file in $(find ./)
do
  newname=$(echo ${file} | sed -e 's/\.\(.*\)\././')
  mv ${file} ${newname}
done
```

Comment: Don’t do `for file in $(find …); do …;` instead, do `find . … -exec …`.  Note that `$file` and `$newname` should be quoted (in double quotes); putting them in braces doesn’t accomplish anything when used on a free-standing variable, like `${file}` in your answer.  Does this sound familiar?